# how to replace matter.js circle with round png image

Tags: javascript, sprite, p5.js, matter.js

So I'm making a simple coin dropping game I have already created coin objects with a simple Bodies.circle. However I want to replace that with a coin image. This is what I have so far.....

```
    this.body = Bodies.circle(x, y, r, {

    restitution: 1,
    friction:0,
    render: { 
        sprite:{ 
            texture: 'images/coin.png'
        }
    }
    });
    this.r = r; 
    World.add(world, this.body);  
}
```

Comment: It depends on how you render your matter.js physics objects. You could simply request the position of the body with this.body.position.x (and y) and simply place your png at that position (do that 30 times per second)

Comment: What's the problem with the code now exactly?

Comment: Related: [how to round an image in matter.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72468816/how-to-round-an-image-in-matter-js/72849934#72849934)

Comment: Also related: [How to fill shapes with image in p5.js and matter.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66381193/how-to-fill-shapes-with-image-in-p5-js-and-matter-js/77782719#77782719)